# Fullcalendar use for loop in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I want to use a `for` loop in AJAX with the FullCalendar JQuery plugin.
Is it possible?

My code is

```
$("#frm").attr("action","readCountOfAdv.do");
$("#frm").ajaxSubmit(advCount);

var advCount = {
        success : function(resultData) {
            var result = JSONtoString(resultData);
            var array = result.split(",");

            data = {events: [
                for(i=1 ; i<=arry.length ; i++){
                    if(i < array.length){
                        {
                            title: 'a',
                            start: '2012-05-14'
                        },
                    }else if(i == array.length){
                        {
                            title: 'a',
                            start: '2012-05-14'
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]};
            calendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', data );

        },
        type : "post",
        dataType : "json",
        error : function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    };
```

Comment: What is the intended output and what do you get instead? Any error messages?

Comment: I had Syntax Error. I think It be rasied for loop. that resultData include day of date and count. i want to write It to every resultData.day.

Comment: you have a typo in your for loop (`arry` instead of `array`). Could it possibly be that? Also, `Array` is a keyword in JS, I would avoid using `array` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions I can think of.
The first relies on Array.prototype.map - not available in some older browsers, but easily replaced (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility)

```
data = {
    events: array.map(function(element,i){
        if(i < array.length){
            return {
                title: 'a',
                start: '2012-05-14'
            };
        }else if(i == array.length){
            return {
                title: 'a',
                start: '2012-05-14'
            };
        }
    }
};
```

The second does without, instead using Array.prototype. It is somewhat less elegant.

```
data = { events: [] };
array.forEach(function(element,i){
    if(i < array.length){
        data.events.append({
            title: 'a',
            start: '2012-05-14'
        });
    }else if(i == array.length){
        data.events.append({
            title: 'a',
            start: '2012-05-14'
        });
    }
});
```

EDIT: There's a third option, based on the second one, that is perhaps slightly more elegant than the second.

```
data = {
    events: (function(arrayIn){
        arrayOut=[];
        arrayIn.forEach(function(element,i){
            if(i < arrayIn.length){
                arrayOut.append({
                    title: 'a',
                    start: '2012-05-14'
                });
            }else if(i == array.length){
                arrayout.append({
                    title: 'a',
                    start: '2012-05-14'
                });
            }
        });
        return arrayOut;
    })(array)
}
```